# Making PyPy toolchain input-language-independent

Tags: pypy, rpython

What would be the steps involved in updating the PyPy toolchain, to allow one to substitute RPython with any well-defined statically-typed language (e.g "RRuby", "RJavaScript", or any subsets of Haskell or ML or C that map to RPython's functionality)?  Would it be possible to define an AST generator for each of those languages and feed that AST into the toolchain?  Or is RPython completely baked into the toolchain?

I was thinking something like this would redefine the PyPy project, at least the first goal of creating "A set of tools for implementing interpreters for interpreted languages".  It would completely decouple Python from that aspect of the project.  So one could write e.g. "RuRu" instead of just a "PyPy-based Ruby implementation".

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible answers to this question.  One answer is that yes, you can try, but it's not really interesting.  Yes, you can play with a different front-end that feeds into the same toolchain; but then you're only changing the syntax, and that's it.

Let's take the example of writing "RuRu" in "RRuby" rather than in RPython.  If you only change the front-end of PyPy, the RRuby language you get is mostly just RPython with a different syntax.  The toolchain will still assume that RRuby handles the same kinds of objects, like strings, lists, tuples, dicts, all with a Python-ish behavior.

That's probably not what you want from a real RRuby.  You want instead some subset of Ruby, with a Ruby-ish behavior.  Supporting that into PyPy is much more work.